# RAM compatibility for HPE servers

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant, hpe

I ordered a HPE ProLiant DL325 G10 server. It comes with a AMD EPYC 7401P and 32GB (2x16GB) DDR4 2666MT/s 2Rx8 RDIMMs.  I'd like to add more RAM to it. I'm wondering if I can buy non-HPE branded RAM and save a bunch of money and have no compatibility issues. I looked up the module part numbers for the 16GB & 32GB sticks HPE sells. I found them a lot cheaper without the HPE sticker. Will these work perfectly without any issues? And is there really anything different in the hardware in HPE RAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a modern ProLiant Gen10 server, you will receive alerts at power-on expressing that the RAM in the system is not **Genuine HPE Smart Memory**.

Here are the details of [Smart Memory certification](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03926319).

I think it's worse having mixed memory types installed. This RAM status will likely add an entry to the ILO and IML log every boot and while it will technically work, it may be a better idea to find a discounted price for HPE-specific RAM.

In my environments, I'd opt for used/refurbished HPE RAM versus buying unbranded or generics.

> EVENT (29 Dec 07:32): POST Information: Processor 1, DIMM 1 could not
>   be authenticated as genuine HP SmartMemory. Enhanced and extended HP
>   SmartMemory features
>
> Integrated Management Log Severity: INFORMATIONAL

Comment: I would remove all included HPE RAM and replace them with non-HPE RAM (8x 32GB). There would be no mixing HPE with non-HPE RAM.  So other than iLO logging the RAM as non-genuine, everything *should* work fine? And will it display non-HPE RAM in iLO's RAM health status? Also the error states "enhanced & extended ... features" - is this BS or are there really some enhanced features?

Comment: I linked to the description of [HPE Smart Memory](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03926319). I think it's dangerous to go into this situation _planning_ to do the wrong thing rather than work on pricing or finding a lower cost way to get the right product. Non-HP RAM will work, but it's just not a worthwhile risk for some environments. As a consultant, I'll use non-HP RAM in a pinch if I am desperate, but it's never long-term. If I encounter an environment where non-HP RAM has been used, I usually let the customer know that someone took a shortcut at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can buy cheaper RAM from third parties and have it work in the system, provided you buy the *correct* RAM (ECC RDIMM/LRDIMM DDR4-2666 1.2V CL19).

Keep in mind that third party hardware isn't covered by the HPE warranty, and it even explicitly states that your warranty is void if a hardware failure is caused by third party hardware. If your third party RAM blows up the motherboard, no HPE warranty service for you. Of course that's extremely unlikely, but it is a risk you have to account for.